# Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column 'pdd' at row 1

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble trying to set the `PDD`(patient death date) to null on PHPMYADMIN until such death date comes;  also on the client end then I can check for `NULL` data to use it.

Could anyone suggest me a solution, please ?

```
patientnhs_no   hospital_no sex     name    surname     dob     address     pls  pdd    
1001001001      6000001      m     john     smith   1941-01-01  Bournmouth  1    0000-00-00
```

(PDD should be null if is alive or death date if died)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As the message error says, you need to Increase the length of your column to fit the length of the data you are trying to insert (`0000-00-00)`

**EDIT 1**:

Following your comment, I run a test table:

```
mysql> create table testDate(id int(2) not null auto_increment, pdd date default null, primary key(id));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.20 sec)
```

Insertion:

```
mysql> insert into testDate values(1,'0000-00-00');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
```

**EDIT 2:**

So, aparently you want to insert a NULL value to `pdd` field as your comment states ?
You can do that in 2 ways like this:

Method 1:

```
mysql> insert into testDate values(2,'');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.06 sec)
```

Method 2:

```
mysql> insert into testDate values(3,NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)
```

**EDIT 3:**

You failed to change the default value of `pdd` field. Here is the syntax how to do it (in my case, I set it to NULL in the start, now I will change it to NOT NULL)

```
mysql> alter table testDate modify pdd date not null;
Query OK, 3 rows affected, 1 warning (0.60 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely pushing a *string* `'NULL'` to the table, rather then an actual `NULL`, but other things may be going on as well, an illustration:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE date_test (pdd DATE NOT NULL);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO date_test VALUES (NULL);
ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'pdd' cannot be null
mysql> INSERT INTO date_test VALUES ('NULL');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.05 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                  |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'pdd' at row 1 |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM date_test;
+------------+
| pdd        |
+------------+
| 0000-00-00 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE date_test MODIFY COLUMN pdd DATE NULL;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.15 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO date_test VALUES (NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM date_test;
+------------+
| pdd        |
+------------+
| 0000-00-00 |
| NULL       |
+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```