# SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'id_paket' at row 1

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel

> SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'id_paket' at
>   row 1 (SQL: insert into `tbl_pesanan` (`id_paket`, `kode_bmn`,
>   `kode_unit`, `jenis_barang`, `kuantitas`, `satuan_ukuran`,
>   `status_pesanan`) values (18,18, 1010101002,1010101002, 1001,1001,
>   ASus,ASus, 6,6, UNit,UNit, 1))

what happened, can you help me?

```
public function store_pesanan(request $request,$id){
        if(!Session::get('login')){
            return redirect('/login')->with('alert','Kamu harus login dulu');
        }
        else{
            DB::table('tbl_paket')
            ->where('id_paket',$id)
            ->update(['status_paket' => $request->status_paket]);

            $data = new ModelPesanan();
            $data->id_paket         = implode(',', $request->input('id_paket'));
            $data->kode_bmn         = implode(',', $request->input('kode_bmn'));
            $data->kode_unit        = implode(',', $request->input('kode_unit'));
            $data->jenis_barang     = implode(',', $request->input('jenis_barang'));
            $data->kuantitas        = implode(',', $request->input('kuantitas'));
            $data->satuan_ukuran    = implode(',', $request->input('satuan_ukuran'));
            $data->status_pesanan   = $request->get('status_pesanan');
            $data->save();

            Alert::success('Sukses!', 'Berhasil Menambahkan Pesanan!');
            return redirect ('/daftar_paket');  
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column 'pdd' at row 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077157/warning-1265-data-truncated-for-column-pdd-at-row-1)

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that you are trying to insert a value in the field `id_paket` that is too long. Check the type and size of `id_paket` and compare to what your query is sending: `18,18`

Comment: id_paket = int(11)

Comment: So it's supposed to be an integer filed and you are passing a string `18,18`. The comma is not a valid character.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to save arrays into a single field unless they are intended to be kept as a json.

I think you are trying to create two `ModelPesanan`? if so, assuming id_paket is a foreign key and the key of the id_paket array is the same for all the other arrays in the request then you can try:

```
  DB::table('tbl_paket')
  ->where('id_paket',$id)
  ->update(['status_paket' => $request->status_paket]);

  foreach($request->input('id_paket') as $index => $idPaket){
    $data = new ModelPesanan();
    $data->id_paket         = $request->input('id_paket')[$index];
    $data->kode_bmn         = $request->input('kode_bmn')[$index];
    $data->kode_unit        = $request->input('kode_unit')[$index];
    $data->jenis_barang     = $request->input('jenis_barang')[$index];
    $data->kuantitas        = $request->input('kuantitas')[$index];
    $data->satuan_ukuran    = $request->input('satuan_ukuran')[$index];
    $data->status_pesanan   = $request->get('status_pesanan');
    $data->save();
  }

  Alert::success('Sukses!', 'Berhasil Menambahkan Pesanan!');
  return redirect ('/daftar_paket');
```

Comment: by calling 1 id_paket

Comment: sorry i'm not understanding.. so are you trying to store the data as an array? you mentioned that your id_paket is an integer field