# Laravel Enum - storing values in snake case

Tags: laravel, enums

I'm using `BenSampo/laravel-enum` in a project and getting values as a string but my client wants to store the values in snake case.

**Migration**:

```
            $table->enum('stock', StockStatus::getValues())->default(StockStatus::OUT_OF_STOCK);
```

**StockStatus.php**

```
const OUT_OF_STOCK = 'Out of Stock';
const BACK_ORDER =   'Back Order';
const IN_STOCK =   'In Stock';
```

**View**

```
  <select class="form-control" name="stock" id="stock">
    <option>{{\App\Enums\StockStatus::OUT_OF_STOCK()}}</option>
    <option>{{\App\Enums\StockStatus::IN_STOCK()}}</option>
    <option>{{\App\Enums\StockStatus::BACK_ORDER()}}</option>
  </select>
```

**Controller**

```
 $product->stock = $request->stock;
```

I want to achieve something like:

1. "In Stock" will be shown in the frontend.(which is ok for now)
2. If 'In Stock" is selected, `in_stock` will be stored in the database. I have tried to pass the data with `Str::snake` in my controller. But it returns `Warning: 1265 Data truncated`

Comment: Can you potentially use the Str::slug function and then replace the - with _? https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-str-slug

Comment: I need to store values in Snake_case only.

Comment: Yes, if the snake function isn’t working, try using the slug method and then replace the - with _ which will make it snake case...

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: [Your error solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077157/warning-1265-data-truncated-for-column-pdd-at-row-1)